# New Product DROPDOWN Attribute (IF THEN ELSE)

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes, product-attribute, dropdown-attribute

I made a new Product Dropdown Attribute that will show on a Group Product Page.

My idea:

```
<?php IF echo $this->htmlEscape($_item->getAttributeText('etickettype')) = 'GREEN'?>
<img src="/Picture-GREEN.jpg">
<?php IF echo $this->htmlEscape($_item->getAttributeText('etickettype')) = 'RED'?>
<img src="/Picture-RED.jpg">
<?php IF echo $this->htmlEscape($_item->getAttributeText('etickettype')) = 'BLUE'?>
<img src="/Picture-BLUE.jpg">
<?php endif; ?>
```

I know this code is not the correct, but does anyone know how I can find or explain the correct code?

Comment: Should be `if($this->htmlEscape($_item->getAttributeText('etickettype')) == this->__('GREEN'))`

Comment: it works! But easyer then i mean, here is the working code ;-) <img src="/media/wysiwyg/tickettype/<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_item->getAttributeText('etickettype')) ?>.jpg" /> Thanks for all.

Answer (score 3):

I'd use a switch statement instead like this.

```
<?php
    switch ($this->htmlEscape($_item->getAttributeText('etickettype')) {
        case 'GREEN':
            $color="GREEN";
            break;
        case 'RED':
            $color="RED";
            break;
        case 'BLUE':
            $color="BLUE";
            break;
        default:
            $color="NA";
            break;
    }
?>
<img src="/Picture-<?php echo $color;?>.jpg" />
```

Although also I'd say you probably need to figure out what exactly you are doing in the end because even that doesn't seem to be the Magento way but I'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish overall.

Also if the attribute text is always going to be the same you could just spit out that instead like this:

```
<img src="/Picture-<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_item->getAttributeText('etickettype');?>.jpg" />
```

Answer (score 0):

First try to find a product naming conversion

E.g

```
{product name}-{color}.jpg
{product sku}-{color}.jpg
```

Assuming that every product attribute has an image

```
<img src="/<?php echo $product->getName() . '-' . $this->htmlEscape($_item->getAttributeText('etickettype'))?>.jpg">
```

No need to do a if or case statement, if the image may not exist see [Check if file exists before displaying in Magento PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14534309/check-if-file-exists-before-displaying-in-magento-php)